# Yii validation compare against related model's Attribute when create new model

Tags: validation, yii, model, creation

I would like to compare one of a newly created model's attributes against a related model's attribute when validating.
I'm searching since a while and do not really find any useful informations.

In one of my other models, when updating, this piece of code is working (in the model):

```
public function compareWithDescendantsKeszDb() {
    $gyermek = $this->descendants(1)->find();

    if ($gyermek <> null) {
        if ($gyermek->keszDb < $this->keszDb) {
            $this->addError('keszDb', Yii::t('validation', 'some error message'));
        }
    }
}

public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('keszDb', 'compareWithDescendantsKeszDb'),
    );
}
```

but the same approach doesn't seem to be working now, maybe it's because it's a create function now.
I've tried like so (also in model):

```
public function compareWithSzeriaGyartmanyDb() {
    $szeriaGyartmany = SzeriaGyartmany::model()->findByPk($this->szeriaGyartmanyId);

    if ($this->db > $szeriaGyartmany->db) {
        $this->addError('db', Yii::t('validation', "Error: maximum you can save is $szeriaGyartmany->db"));
    }
}

public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('db', 'compareWithSzeriaGyartmanyDb'),
    );
}
```

I hope it's somewhat clear what I would like to achieve.
Can somebody please point me to the right direction?
Thanks a lot!

BR
c

Comment: in fact I don't know. I wanted to echo $this->szeriaGyartmanyId in the error message to check if it exists at all, but it seems always empty.

Comment: At first I wanted to test and put a larger amount in the textfield than what is allowed, and I wanted to show $szeriaGyartmany->db on the form to the user, that it's the maximum what can be saved. But the value was empty. Then I wanted to echo $this->szeriaGyartmanyId in the error message to check if it exists at all, but it also seems empty. That's why I guess something is not okay, but when I put a smaller or equal number, it's seems working. I would like to show the maximum allowed amount in the error message.

Comment: yes, I use it in a lot of other places (in controllers and views, but maybe the problem is that I want to use it now in a model, I don't know...)

Comment: in application log I have found now two warnings:
[12:39:03.610][warning][application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "kooperacioId" of "KooperacioSzeriaGyartmany".
in ...\protected\controllers\KooperacioSzeriaGyartmanyController.php (15)
in ...\index.php (13)

create (475. sor)

[12:39:03.610][warning][application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "szeriaGyartmanyId" of "KooperacioSzeriaGyartmany".
in ...\protected\controllers\KooperacioSzeriaGyartmanyController.php (15)
in ...\index.php (13)
it's strange... I've never met with such

Comment: I think when u call the model method compareWithSzeriaGyartmanyDb() it may be not getting $this->szeriaGyartmanyId .so once You check weahther it gets the valid value

Comment: read some documentation to set the validation safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the safe attribute to validation as shown

```
 public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('db', 'compareWithSzeriaGyartmanyDb','safe'),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Now I can see the variable's value in the error message! Thank you so much!

Comment: notice: in fact I had to add safe to these two variables: array('kooperacioId, szeriaGyartmanyId', 'safe') because these were mentioned in the log as "Failed to set unsafe attribute..."